# Woocommerce partial payment plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am developing a custom payment gateway that once chosen by the user(they choose the method and click on place order) get redirected to an external website, they put their credentials and the amount they want to pay with the card. I am then redirecting to a webhook that takes care of processing that amount. If the amount is enough to pay the total of the order, the order gets marked as finished and redirects to the thank you page. If the amount is not enough, i create a coupon according to that amount and apply it for the order. I then redirect the user to checkout page so that they can choose another method to pay for the rest of the amount. The problem here is that everytime the users presses the place order button (even if the order actually exists) a new order gets created. In addition this process seems quite messy and i would like a better alternative if possible or a solution to the multiple orders.

Comment: This sounds like a requirement. What is your concrete question? Also, you could use a few paragraphs to format your text in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see how the coupon comes into play here to begin with, can't see that making much sense. Your requirement is anything but a common one, so this will probably need quite some modifications to the whole process to work properly & cleanly. Perhaps you should provide users with a dashboard where they can see their orders that have not been fully paid yet, and you offer them to go to the payment gateways from there, to add another payment.